# Run this stored procedure with a null value?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run a stored procedure using the phpmyadmin routine portal:

```
`ADD_PERSON`; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ADD_PERSON`(IN `person_id` DECIMAL(12) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL, IN `first_name` VARCHAR(32), IN `last_name` VARCHAR(32), IN `username` VARCHAR(32)) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER INSERT INTO PERSON(person_id,first_name,last_name,username) VALUES(@person_id_arg,@first_name_arg,@last_name_arg,@username_arg)
```

Then I go to execute:

[image]

And I get the message

[image]

I have tried to use NUll, NOT NULL for the person_id feild and still have an error.

Please advise on how I can correct this error. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL Server? In fact your error says MySQL which is a totally different product. Please correct your tags.

Comment: And ask your question in the positive i.e. how to run this procedure with a null value, not I can't run it with a null value.

Comment: Thank for the feedback. I have modified.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)